# DriveItem-copy c# snippet would cause 'DriveRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Items', how to fix this?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I copied the snippet from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#Request). and Visual Studio would prompt an error 'DriveRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'DriveRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've added a screenshot here

[image: 1]

I tried to downgrade the version of Microsoft.Graph from 5.1 to 4.54, thought It was not compatibile with the latest version because the document driveitem-copy was last updated 8 months ago, and hoping this would fix but the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed.

The snippet on the document is outdated.

changed the code to this:

```
 var parentReference = new ItemReference
            {
                DriveId = newDriveId,
                Id = newItemId
            };

            var name = "Copied Files";


            await graphClient.Drives[targetDriveId].Items[targetItemId]
                .Copy
                .PostAsync(new CopyPostRequestBody 
                {ParentReference=parentReference,Name=name});
```